# What's the difference in new stdClass() and new stdClass?

Tags: php

I'm learning the advance concepts of php. What does `new stdClass` do? I know what `new stdClass();` does.

For eg) `<?php new stdClass(); ? >` creates a new object. Does `<?php new stdClass; ? >` do the same thing? Notice there's no parentheses. Does that make a difference? I can't find documentation on it for php manual.

Comment: Thanks :). I can't find though where the php manual says about creating an object without parentheses?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference. PHP lets you omit the parentheses if you're not passing arguments to the constructor.

Comment: `$a=new stdClass();var_dump($a);` shows `object(stdClass)#1 (0) { }` while `$a= new stdClass;var_dump($a);` shows `object(stdClass)#2 (0) { }`. Why is the difference ?